# Java regex to filter phone numbers

Tags: java, android, regex

I have following example string that needs to be filtered

```
0173556677 (Alice), 017545454 (Bob)
```

This is how phone numbers are added to a text view. I want the text to look like that

```
0173556677;017545454
```

Is there a way to change the text using regular expression. How would such an expression look like? Or do you recommend an other method?

Comment: Have a look at Google's libphonenumber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
String orig = "0173556677 (Alice), 017545454 (Bob)";
String regex = " \\(.+?\\)"; 
String res = orig.replaceAll(regex, "").replaceAll(",", ";");
//                           ^remove all content in parenthesis
//                                                 ^ replace comma with semicolon
```

Comment: In `regex` variable, there is a `?`. I have tried executing the code without `?`, the variable `res` gets `0173556677` rather than `0173556677; 017545454`. `?` in regex sense means optional character. What exactly does it mean here?

Answer (score 2):

Use the expression in `android.util.Patterns`

Access the static variable

`Patterns.PHONE`

or use this expression [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/util/Patterns.java#Patterns.0PHONE) (Android Source Code)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a resource that can guide you :

http://www.zparacha.com/validate-email-ssn-phone-number-using-java-regular-expression/

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with phone numbers separated with any string that does not contain numbers:

```
String orig = "0173556677 (Alice), 017545454 (Bob)";    
String[] numbers = orig.split("\\D+"); //split at everything that is not a digit 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (numbers.length > 0) {
    sb.append(numbers[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) { //concatenate all that is left
        sb.append(";");
        sb.append(numbers[i]);
    }
}
String res = sb.toString();
```

or, with com.google.common.base.Joiner:

```
String[] numbers = orig.split("\\D+"); //split at everything that is not a digit 
String res = Joiner.on(";").join(numbers);
```

PS. There is a minor deviation from the requirements in the best voted example, but it seems I cannot just add one character (should be `replaceAll(", ", ";")`, with a space after the coma, or a `\\s`) and I do not want to mess somebody's code.